# Script is working with jquery 1.3.2 but not with jquery 1.7.2

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add extra input fields but this code works with jquery 1.3 once i try with jquery 1.7. It doesn't work

```
var newTr = $(document.createElement('tr'))
         .attr("id", 'line' + counter);

    newTr.after().html('<td><input type="text" name="name' + counter + 
          '" id="name' + counter + '" value="" style="width:100px;"></td><td><input type="text" name="phone' + counter + 
          '" id="phone' + counter + '" value="" style="width:100px;"></td>');

    newTr.appendTo("#dyTable");
```

I guess there is problem with newTr.after().html() and newTr.appendTo("#dyTable"); Please help me

Comment: You should use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()` for the "id". I don't know what you intend that call to `.after()` to do, but it's pointless to call it without a parameter.  Are there errors in the console?

Comment: I think the error is with newTr.after().html() -- not sure what the .after() is for there. I think you mean newTr.after('html here');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.createElement('tr')` is not needed and you can simply use `$('<tr></tr>')` to create new element. This should work,

`var newTr = $('<tr></tr>').attr("id", 'line' + counter);`

For adding `<td>` content, change, `newTr.after().html('...')` to `newTr.html('...')`. I don't think `after` is required.